# How to implement react-virtual to react-table?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table, react-virtual

I have created a reusable table component using **react-table v8 by tanstack**.
Im now trying to implement **react-virtual by tanstack** to this reusable table. Im using "@tanstack/react-virtual": "^3.0.0-beta.54" and "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.9.2".
Im not finding any example online with the integration of the lates versions of this two libraries. Can somebody help me with this?

```
import type { ReactElement } from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeaderCell,
  TableRow,
} from "./style";
import {
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import type { ColumnDef } from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { useVirtualizer } from "@tanstack/react-virtual";

interface TableProps {
  columns: Array<ColumnDef<any, string>>;
  data: any;
}

function CustomTable(props: TableProps): ReactElement {
  const { columns, data } = props;
  const parentRef = useRef<HTMLTableElement>(null);

  const tableInstance = useReactTable({
    columns,
    data,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });

  const rowVirtualizer = useVirtualizer({
    count: tableInstance.getRowModel().rows.length,
    getScrollElement: () => parentRef.current,
    estimateSize: () => 15,
  });

  return (
    <div ref={parentRef}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          {tableInstance.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(header => {
                  return (
                    <TableHeaderCell key={header.id}>
                      <span>
                        {header.isPlaceholder
                          ? null
                          : flexRender(
                              header.column.columnDef.header,
                              header.getContext()
                            )}
                      </span>
                    </TableHeaderCell>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {tableInstance.getRowModel().rows.map(row => {
            return (
              <TableRow $border key={row.id}>
                {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => {
                  return (
                    <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                      <span>
                        {flexRender(
                          cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                          cell.getContext()
                        )}
                      </span>
                    </TableCell>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomTable;
```